# hibernate change the column name in a select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table (node) with 3 data
- id(pk)
- question
- result

and 2 foreign key (many-to-one)
- LEFT_ID
- RIGHT_ID

here my hbm

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.beans.Nodes" table="node">
        <id name="id" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="question" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="question" />
        </property>
        <property name="result" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="result" />
        </property>


        <many-to-one column="LEFT_ID" name="left" class="com.beans.Nodes" insert="false" update="false"></many-to-one>
        <many-to-one column="RIGHT_ID" name="right" class="com.beans.Nodes" insert="false" update="false"></many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and my bean with getter/setter on LEFT/RIGHT_ID

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "node")
public class Nodes
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column (name = "question")
    private String question;

    @Column ( name = "result")
    private String result;

    private Nodes LEFT_ID;

    private Nodes RIGHT_ID;


    public Nodes getLeftNodes()
    {
        return LEFT_ID;
    }

    public void setLeftNodes(Nodes LEFT_ID)
    {
        this.LEFT_ID=LEFT_ID;
    }

    public Nodes getRightNodes()
    {
        return RIGHT_ID;
    }

    public void setRifhtNodes(Nodes right)
    {
        this.RIGHT_ID=right;
    }
}
```

But when i deploy my project, i have this error

```
**Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Nodes sql="SELECT id, question, result, LEFT_ID_id, RIGHT_ID_id FROM node")**
```

When hibernate is a select, he change the name of the column. LEFT_ID becomes LEFT_ID_id and inevitably he finds nothing !

Why hibernate change the name of the LEFT_ID column ?

thanks

Comment: LEFT_ID is one-to-one relationship, and it's expressed in the table as column <field_name>_id, hence LEFT_ID_id. The join should look something like t1.LEFT_ID_id = t2.id (where t1 and t2 are aliases of the same table)

Comment: ok thanks. But in my hbm, if a take one-to-one relationship, my project works and i can insert a new data but i do not LEFT/RIGHT_ID and hibernate delete my old data. thanks